# Fastest way to delete million of files

Tags: c#, .net, filesystems

I have a list of string which are relative paths. I also have a string which contains root path for those files. Now I am deleting them like this:

```
foreach (var rawDocumentPath in documents.Select(x => x.RawDocumentPath))
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(rawDocumentPath))
    {
        continue;
    }
    string fileName = Path.Combine(storagePath, rawDocumentPath);
    File.Delete(fileName);
}
```

the problem is that I call `Path.Combine` for every file, and it's slow enough. 
How can I speed up this code? I can't delete whole folders, I cannot change current directory (because it affects a whole program)...

I need something like a class which can delete fast several files in specified directory.

Comment: Can't see anything that would slow your code down, the bottleneck with file operations under normal conditions are always the I/O operations. You might try to use multi-threading here e.g. documents.AsParallel().ForAll()

Comment: @MichaelSander I know, but disk can organize deletes in batches, you know, command queues and so on.

Comment: If you knew it was "all" of something you could do a "*.doc" type approach, but when you need to do specifics.. you are more limited

Comment: From my experience using kernel32.dll and its utilities for manipulating files speed the things up. Of course if you're ok with unmanaged code.

Comment: Will be interesting to have a comparative benchmark between the "standard" solution, the parallel execution (or an asynch task) and using directly Windows DLL. Are you sur that Path.Combine is slower than File.Delete ?

Comment: I replaced Path.Combine with manual string concatenation, here I have concatenation of 2 string instead of 3, it's a nice boost. I'l try parallel execution now. And don't forget that files could be placed in remote computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your disk can handle it, parallizing should help a lot:

```
documents.AsParallel().ForAll(
    document =>
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(document.RawDocumentPath))
        {
            string fileName = Path.Combine(storagePath, document.RawDocumentPath);
            File.Delete(fileName);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Well, ForAll + native FileDelete seems to be an answer here. Interesting, some1 downvoted, but didn't write about why :) Some people are really strange...